# rendering not happening in video editing?

Tags: rendering

I am trying to render a animation but it is not working and I have no idea what could be reason . Can anyone help please ? I am sharing the download link of my blender file for your reference. Please help. https://pasteall.org/media/3/9/39cec81f98d39b783d7f81c5b6a9401b.blend

Comment: You have a series of PNG in the Video Sequencer, are you trying to render this sequence or your 3D view scene?

Comment: i think the used files in the video sequencer aren't existing anymore, that's why it isn't rendering anything

Comment: If you're trying to render your scene, you need to deactivate Output > Post Processing > Sequencer. If you're trying to render the PNG sequence that is in your Video Sequencer, we can't test as we don't have your PNG images.

Comment: yes @moonboots i am trying to render the png in the video sequencer

Comment: but the file do exist @Chris which are in the video sequencer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change resolution to an even number:

[image]

Then it worked for me, as i tried it.

Comment: yes , it finally worked. Thank you so much @Chris

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: omfg, its been 1 hour I'm trying everything. Well, not everything it seems. Your trick WORKED. I don't know how you figured that out. Thank you so much.

Comment: Awesome! That worked for me too. I had an odd number in the resolution. Changed it to an even number it it worked without a hitch! Thank you!